# Finding a letter in a list

Tags: python, string, list, boolean, letter

I have a problem that states: Write a function that takes, as an argument, a list and a string,and returns a Boolean based on whether or not all of the letters in the string appear somewhere in the list. Here is what I have so far.

```
def findLetters(myList, myString):
    for letter in myString:
        if letter in myList:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: this will return True at the first match, not if all letters are in the list.

Comment: Please state your question

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic solution that's closer to what you've started:

```
def findLetters(myList, myString):
    found_all = False
    for s in myString:        # check each letter in the string
        if s in myList:       # see if it is in the list
            found_all = True  # keep going if found
        else:
            found_all = False # otherwise set `found` to False 
            break             # and break out of the loop

    return found_all          # return the result

result = findLetters(['a', 'l', 'i', 's', 't'], 'mlist')

# 'm' is not in the list
print result # False 

# all letters in the string are in the list; 
# ignores any extra characters in the list that are not in the string
result = findLetters(['a', 'l', 'i', 's', 't', 'p'], 'alist')

print result # True
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning True if any letter match in myString, not all letter in myString.
You could do the other way around, if any letter not match in myString, return False

```
def findLetters(myList, myString):
    for letter in myString:
        if letter not in myList:
            return False
    return True
```

OR use builtin function [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

```
def findLetters(myList, myString):
  return all(letter in myList for letter in myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map all letters using a lambda which creates a list of boolean values for all letters in `my_string`.

The function `all` returns `true` if all values in the `l` list ar `True`.

```
def find_letters(my_list, my_string): 
    l = map(lambda x: x in my_list, my_string)
    return all(l)

print(find_letters(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'cab'))
```